# Hibernate createAlias() with withClause parameter results in lazy collection

Tags: java, hibernate

When creating a hibernate criteria query that uses the 'withClause' the association is always lazy.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.setFetchMode("a.b", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("b.someOtherColumn", 5));

List list=criteria.list();
```

In this case, "b" would result in a lazy collection. Is there a way around this that still uses criteria queries? I have to use the withClause to get the correct root entity.

Comment: show your A and B class code too please

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.someOtherColumn", 5));

List list=criteria.list();
```

Comment: This is not the same query. I need to return "a" in in all cases, not just when b.someOtherColumn = 5. I only want the association "b" when someOtherColumn = 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **fetch mode** for the collection *b* to **JOIN**:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("b.someOtherColumn", 5));
criteria.setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.JOIN);

List list=criteria.list();
```

Comment: This still results in  the collection "b" being lazily loaded.